# Class Dependencies WPF Control

Tags: wpf

WPF is really amazing for many reasons and one of them is that it allows us to change the controls inside a control. As example if we take a ListBox. We can change the panel from StackPanel to WrapPanel and it will still work (I guess its obviously that ListBox and WrapPanel don't share any class dependencies hence why it works).

Here is an example what I mean with class dependencies.

```
public class Test1
{
 public Test2 t;

 public Test1(Test2 t)
 {
   this.t = t;
 }
}

public class Test2
{
  public string someStr;
}
```

Now the instance could be injected/inserting like this:

```
Test2 test2 = new Test2();
test2.someStr = "Hello";

Test1 test1 = new Test1();
test1.t = test2;
```

Or instance could be inserted like this:

```
Test2 test2 = new Test2();
test2.someStr = "Hello";
Test1 test1 = new Test1(test2);
```

There are few other ways to do this but I hope that you guys now get the point.

So now after we know how to inject the instance lets try to do so in WPF with this following example:

I have a CustomControl. My CustomControl is a little bit complex because it has rows and columns. Futhermore the CustomControl is not derivering from a DataGrid. In fact it is derivering from an ItemsControl.

As I mentioned it has columns and rows or to be more precise the rows need to know about the columns. Thats where I would like to insert the instance of columns in a row. How do i do that in WPF?

Here is a simple plain example of my problem:

Lets say the VisualTree of the CustomControl looks like this:

```
CustomControl
+ Grid
 + Border
  + ContentPresenter
   + Headers
 + DockPanel
  + Border
   + ContentPresenter
    + Rows
```

As you can see the Rows are far away from Headers and I would like to get/insert the instance of Headers to the Rows without finding the Headers.

Rows and Headers classes look like this:

```
class Row : ContentControl
{
  List<Column> Headers;
  ...
}

class Headers : ContentControl
{
  List<Column> Cols = new List<Column>()
  public Headers()
  {
    this.Cols.Add(...);
    this.Cols.Add(...);
  }
 ...
}
```

And the problem is how to do something like this:

```
this.rows.Headers = columns.Cols;
```

I have searched on the internet and many people have suggested me to let the row use VisualTreeHelper and then to travel up the tree to find the Cols. In fact I tried to do so and after monitoring my CustomControl with a Performance Profiler Tool, I figured that it's exactly the step where every row stumbles up the tree to find header that takes the most of the time. Therefore lets not use VisualTreeHelper and lets use injection like I described in example with Test1 and Test2 above.

Any suggestions? Is there maybe a pattern for this?

EDITED: @Benjamin. To use RedSlider = GetTemplateChild("RedSlider") inside the OnApplyTemplate is a great solution but it doesnt work for me because my case is more complex. In my case i really need to insert the instance somehow. Here is an example of my case where I cannot use GetTemplateChild inside the OnAppyTemplate method.

This is Control for Sliders.

```
class CustomSliders : ContentControl
{
}
```

The style for CustomSlider looks like this:

```
 <Style x:Key="mySliders" TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomSliders}">
    <Style.Setter Property="Template">
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomSliders}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Slider x:Name="PART_RedSLider" />
     <Slider x:Name="PART_GreenSlider" Grid.Row="1"/>
     <Slider x:Name="PART_BlueSlider" Grid.Row="2"/>
     <Slider x:Name="PART_AlphaSlider" Grid.Row="3"/>
    </Grid>
    </ContentTemplate>
   </Style>
```

And this is the ControlTemplate of my CustomControl called ColorPicker.

```
<ContentTemplate TargetType="Picker">
    <DockPanel>
     <ContentControl DockPanel.Dock="Left" Style="{StaticResource mySliders}"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="PART_ColorPresenter" 
                   DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                   Margin="5"/>
    </Grid> 
</ControlTemplate>
```

In this example the GetTemplatedChild method which will be executed inside OnApplyTemplate of ColorPicker wont work because it cannot find the PART_RedSLider which is inside CustomSliders.

GetTemplateChild cannot find everything down the VisualTree.

Because GetTemplatedChild wont work to solve this complex template structure many people suggest me to travel recrusivly up or down the tree by using the VisualTreeHelper.Find(). Though like I explained in the question I dont want to use the recrusive way. I want to insert the instance..

Comment: Can you show some code where you are tavelling up the Visual tree?

Comment: @RV1987 There is not much to show except that I am using VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(..) till the parent is the HeaderPresenter (which holds a list of headers). But with help of Dependency Injection I could simply insert the list of headers without traveling up the tree.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question; it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Please consider revising with more detail and some code samples

Comment: @Benjamin I have edited my question. I think how you should be able to get an idea.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, Kent Boogaarts answer is right on the mark. You have dependencies in your control and these are handled by specifying this as part of your controls contract via the `TemplatePartAttribute`.

Comment: @Benjamin TemplatePartAttribute doesnt inject me the instance, does it?

Answer (score 1):

As I have already stated, Kent Boogaarts answer is technically correct but I think you probably require more information to aid your understanding.

Imagine the control you are writing is a colour picker. The control has 4 `Sliders` for changing the red, green, blue and alpha values and the end result is displayed beside the sliders in a `Rectangle`. A mock-up is shown below:

[image]

This control has 5 dependencies in order for it to work correctly; 4 `Sliders` and 1 `FrameworkElement` for displaying the end result.

What this means is that in my `ControlTemplate` I am expecting to see 4 sliders and 1 `FrameworkElement` that are *named*. The slider that controls the red value, for example, could be called **"PART_RedSlider"** (the name can be anything you want but the recommended approach is to prefix the name with "PART_").

An example template may look something like this:

```
<!-- Typically this would be defined in a style -->
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ColorPicker">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Slider x:Name="PART_RedSLider" />
    <Slider x:Name="PART_GreenSlider" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Slider x:Name="PART_BlueSlider" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <Slider x:Name="PART_AlphaSlider" Grid.Row="3"/>

    <Rectangle x:Name="PART_ColorPresenter" 
                   Grid.Column="1" 
                   Grid.RowSpan="4" 
                   Margin="5"/>
    </Grid> 
</ControlTemplate>
```

Now in your controls code you would override the `OnApplyTemplate()` method, like so:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    RedSlider = GetTemplateChild("PART_RedSlider") as Slider;
    GreenSlider = GetTemplateChild("PART_GreenSlider") as Slider;
    BlueSlider = GetTemplateChild("PART_BlueSlider") as Slider;
    AplhaSlider = GetTemplateChild("PART_AlphaSlider") as Slider;

    ColorPresenter = GetTemplateChild("PART_ColorPresenter") as FrameworkElement;
}
```

You now have access to the named parts of your `ControlTemplate`. You can then do whatever you want to these controls in your code (set default property values, hookup event handlers, etc).

Now you may be wondering where the `TemplatePartAttribute` comes into all this. The thing is, this attribute is purely for documentation purposes so that tools (such as Expression Blend) can assist other people creating a custom template.

The attribute is applied to the class you are writing like so:

```
[TemplatePart(Name="PART_RedSlider", Type=typeof(Slider)]
[TemplatePart(Name="PART_GreenSlider", Type=typeof(Slider)]
[TemplatePart(Name="PART_BlueSlider", Type=typeof(Slider)]
[TemplatePart(Name="PART_AlphaSlider", Type=typeof(Slider)]
[TemplatePart(Name="PART_ColorPresenter", Type=typeof(FrameworkElement)]
public class ColorPicker
```

A piece of advice is to *never* assume that the template will include a named part. Your control should still function (to the best of it's ability) without the named part being present. The guidance from Microsoft is that you should not throw exceptions if a named part is missing (I.E. your application can still run even though your control will not work as expected).

E.G.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    RedSlider = GetTemplateChild("RedSlider") as Slider;

    if (RedSlider != null)
    {
        // Only do anything if the named part is present.
    }
}
```

You should also try to use the lowest base class possible for named parts. E.G. in my example, the named parts for the `Sliders` could be of type `RangeBase` rather than `Slider` so that of types of range controls can be used.

Finally, your class should have variables that hold references to your named parts which are retrieved during the call to `OnApplyTemplate`. Do not try and find the controls each time you want to use them.

So now you need to apply this to your control which is dependant on the `Row` and `Header` controls so these need to be present in your `ControlTemplate` (I will assume a single `Row` and `Header` for simplicity).

First of all document your `CustomControl` with the `TemplatePartAttribute` like so:

```
[TemplatePart(Name="PART_Header", Type=typeof(Header)]
[TemplatePart(Name="PART_Row", Type=typeof(Row)]
public class CustomControl : Control
{
    // etc...
```

Now make sure you have these controls as named parts in your `ControlTemplate` like so:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="CustomControl">
    <Grid>

        <!-- other elements omitted -->

    <Header x:Name="PART_Header" />
    <Row x:Name="PART_Row" />

    </Grid> 
</ControlTemplate>
```

And then you use the `OnApplyTemplate()` method like this:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    myHeader = GetTemplateChild("PART_Header") as Header;
    myRow = GetTemplateChild("PART_Row") as Row;

    if ((myHeader != null) && (myRow != null))
    {
        myRow.Headers = myHeader.Cols;
    }
}
```

Comment: I posted an answer to yours. Please read it and you will hopefully understand that OnApplyTemplate wont work to find all controls in VisualTree.

Comment: @cyberist - have you made any progress with this? has my update helped you at all?

Comment: Well your solution is a good one but still not exactly what I need. I haven't made any progress with this yet but the workaround does work for now. That is to use VisualTreeHelper and wait till its API finds the desired UIElement. :) I will update you when I figure out something better.

Comment: Perhaps you could post some of your actual control code & xaml and we would be able to see where you may be going wrong.

Comment: Its a class design question thing.. Insering instances into control. Kinda like pattern question thing.

Comment: What I have shown you _is_ the pattern that is used for designing custom controls. Looking at your response to this in your edited question I think you have missed the point a bit and posting your code  might help me point you in the right direction. At the end of the day though its up to you.

Comment: I know its up to me. And as I have answered your. Searching for the ElementName in OnApplyTemplate works online for that specific controls template and now for the whole VisualTree. And I need the whole VisualTree. I need a way to insert a instance from 1 level of the VisualTree in the 15 level of the VisualTree.

Answer (score 0):

If your custom control has specific requirements regarding its visual tree, you can declare these using [`TemplatePartAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatepartattribute.aspx)s and use resolve them during [`OnApplyTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate.aspx).

Comment: Sorry mate but that is what I am doing right now. Now at OnApplyTemplate of each row I run up the tree and search for the headers. I am looking for Dependency Injection or at least something similiar to Dependency Injection. Maybe some instance sharing pattern.

Comment: Hard to help further without seeing your code and where exactly you're stuck/suboptimal.

Comment: I think its a general problem. Whenever you write a custom control you have parts further down the tree that need some properties from control owner class. Seems many people use VisualTreeHelper to get the way up to the owner class. I am looking for another way to inject/insert the instance. Rows are sitting pretty deep down the tree and they need the instance of the owner class (which is the custom control class itself).

Comment: Control owner class could set an attached property on the owned instances. Owned instances could bind with relative source FindAncestory. There are many ways to skin this cat.

Comment: I think I would more like to inject/insert the value. FindAncestor is exactly running up the tree like I do currently in code. Setting an attached propery that inherits down the tree isnt really that much powerful in cases where you have thousands of rows. Even the documentation of wpf on msdn says that inherting has impact on performance. As far I know about C# inserting the instance would be really the best prettiest object oriented way to do this. But please tell me if I am wrong. How come its not possible to do it in WPF when even WinForms supports it. :)